# Unable to retrieve converted schema in Tridion

Tags: 2013, schema

Recently i have migrated my database and CME to SDL Tridion 2013 . Publishing and creating of components are success. 
But when i try to edit a schema or copy a schema and try to open its design I get the following errors.

1. Unable to save schema
2. Unable to retrieve converted schema.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam, I have reformatted your question to make it a little easier to understand, you may want to add a specific question to the text.

Comment: Can you post what's in the "Show details" and if there's anything in the Tridion event log?

Comment: Tridion event log gives "System Error" . Show details is the pop up which i have shown in the screenshot .

Comment: Can you post stack trace from Tridion event log?

Comment: System error.
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.ValidateMustUnderstand(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperation)

Comment: Above comment is the stack trace which i get during the saving of schema

Comment: Do you only get this error when clicking the Design tab? What happens when you click the Source tab? If it works please could you post the output here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your valuable responses and we have figured out the issue with the support from SDL Tridion

Note : we have all the DTC configurations in place .

Resolution : In Tridion_Home/bin/TcmServiceHost.exe.config .
In the bindings the transaction protocol is changed to OLEtransactions from WSAtomicTransaction11.
Previously it was written as:

```
<binding name="CoreService_netTcpBinding" transactionFlow="true" 
         transactionProtocol="WSAtomicTransaction11" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:30:00" 
         openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
```

It has been changed to:

```
<binding name="CoreService_netTcpBinding" transactionFlow="true" 
         transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
         closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:30:00">
```

Answer (score 3):

Had a similiar problem with schemas on a fresh install of 2013 in Windows 2012
It turned out that DTC had been installed but not configured.
We just enabled everything, but check older version installation instructions for the actual DTC configuration required, I am sure I recall it was a requirement in earlier versions.
Security Settings
[x] Network DTC Access
Client and Administration
[x] Allow Remote Clients
Transaction Manager Communication
[x] Allow Inbound [x] Allow Outbound
(0) No authentication Required

[x] Enable XA Transations [x] Enable SNA LU 6.2 Transactions

(will update with a screen shot when I have more points)